# Trying to call a method in an if statement but i am getting an error CS7036

Tags: c#

I am trying to call my method in a if statement but I am receiving a error CS7036   There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sourceForestName' of 'FixTheDomain.CreateTrust(string, string)'

This is the method im calling

```
public void CreateTrust(string sourceForestName, string targetForestName)
    {
        Forest sourceForest = Forest.GetForest(new DirectoryContext(
            DirectoryContextType.Forest, sourceForestName));

        Forest targetForest = Forest.GetForest(new DirectoryContext(
            DirectoryContextType.Forest, targetForestName));

        // create an inbound forest trust

        sourceForest.CreateTrustRelationship(targetForest,
            TrustDirection.Outbound);
```

Here is where im calling it

```
private void FixTrust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        if (Validate() == true)
        {
            CreateTrust();
        }  

    }
```

Im really not grasping where it wants me to get those parameters from in my if.

Comment: Hint: What do you expect `CreateTrust()` to do?

Comment: You're calling `CreateTrust()` without passing any parameter for `sourceForestName` or `targetForestName`. You need to pass two strings to it.

Comment: Also, are you intentionally calling `Validate()` twice? Your code could be simplified to `if (Validate()) { CreateTrust(sourceForest, targetForest); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler wants you to call the method with the two parameters it requires

```
CreateTrust("Forest1", "Forest2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
 CreateTrust();
```

inside of your if. CreateTrust requires 2 string parameters. So you need to call:

```
 CreateTrust(string1,string2); or CreateTrust("something","something");
```

replace string1 and string2 with actual variables.